# How do you keep from being tied to a CMS?

Tags: content-management-system

I'd like to use a CMS like Joomla, something else, whatever I need.  I'm worried though that I'll be tied to that CMS forever.

If I design a PHP now and retrieve my database results, I put them where I want.  How can create what I want and have it work with a given CMS without losing my freedom?

I don't mind a whole lot if I only have a add a small amount of classes to inherit.  I can remove them later (easier said that done with lots of pags).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are wise to be considering lock-in before you begin. I've implemented a few CMS-based systems, and struggled with some bad choices. There are costs and benefits to any tool you select, but there is no good way to know which system is right without doing some significant requirements analysis. Joomla is a capable system, but has very different characteristics from Drupal, or Alfresco, or Plone.

To some extent, once your users start putting their content into the system you choose, you will have to work very hard to avoid being tied to that system forever. And if you do a really good job of it, your users will not *want* to migrate to another system.

A couple of things to consider in your analysis:

- pay attention to the customization language(s), particularly in light of the skillset of the team that will have to support the tool after go-live. Alfresco (java) might be a poor choice for a python shop, for example.
- make sure you understand how the tool manages binary data. You can configure Plone to manage attachments as blobs in the file system rather than ZODB, but the default setup isn't correct for every organization.
- pay close attention to the way the toolset handles security, authentication, and authorization, and what choices it gives you to connect to your current (or planned) user databases. A tool that allows you to easily externalize your auth can be the difference between scalability and support nightmares.
- indexing and search matter, good tools make life easier. Bad tools suck.
- a good tool should have useful export capabilities. The harder you have to work to extract your metadata and content, the worse the tool.